# Help wiht adding fullcalendar.io to a WordPress page

Tags: functions, javascript, calendar

I've been trying to add [this calendar](https://fullcalendar.io) to my wordpress page. And I've followed the documentation, but it's still not showing up. This is what I've done.

I first added this to my child theme functions file:

```
function fullcalendar_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script('fullcalendar', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js", false, null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fullcalendar');
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "fullcalendar_jquery_enqueue", 11);

function load_styles() {
    wp_register_style('fullcalendarcss', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css');
    wp_register_style('fullcalendarprintcss', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fullcalendarcss');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fullcalendarprintcss');
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_styles');
```

Then I added this JS to my custom.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var calendar = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
    });
});
```

And then I added `<div id='calendar'></div>` to one of my pages, but the calendar is not showing up. In the console, it's showing "Uncaught TypeError".

Can someone please take a look and let me know what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Does fullcalendar's script require jQuery? If so, you should pass an array containing `'jquery'` instead of `false` as the 3rd argument (dependencies) of the call to `wp_register_script()`, like so: `wp_register_script( 'fullcalendar', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js", array( 'jquery' ), null, true);` This will ensures jQuery is loaded before the script you are enqueing so that the dependency is satisfied. If it still doesn't work, also check the JS console for any warning or error that should give some hints.

Comment: Hey @Iceable, thank you for the reply! I've tried what you suggested, passing an array containing jquery and the JS console shows up the following: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at e (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:8)
    at e (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    ...` and I'm not sure what that means? Is that still a jQuery not loading before them issue or? Again, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

First I passed what Iceable suggested and also added moment script above, like so

```
wp_register_script('moment', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js");
    wp_register_script( 'fullcalendar', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js", array( 'jquery' ), null, true);
```

and then I edited JS like so

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  })

});
```

And it showed up!